# Diff: ignoring lines with just tabs

Tags: regex, diff

I'm trying to diff files, and determine if they are the same, but ignoring ALL whitespace.

When using `diff`, the `-b` tells `diff` to ignore whitespace on a given line.  The `-B` option tells it to ignore all blank lines.  But, if you have a line which contains only spaces, the `-B` and `-b` don't seem to work together.

I've resorted to using the `-I` option, where I want diff to ignore all lines which only contain whitespaces, which works fine when the line contains only spaces, but the `\t` doesn't seem to match tab characters.

I found one reference online that mentioned that you need to use POSIX regexp, but POSIX states that `:blank:` will match any whitespace (including tab).  That does not work either.

Here's a sample of what I'm trying to do.  Ideally, my `diff` line would state that `t1.txt`, `t2.txt` and `t3.txt` were all the same.

```
bash#> echo hi > t1.txt
bash#> echo hi > t2.txt
bash#> echo hi > t3.txt
bash#> echo " " >> t2.txt
bash#> echo -e "\t" >> t3.txt
bash#> diff -BbaNq -I "^[ \t]*$" t1.txt t2.txt
bash#> diff -BbaNq -I "^[ \t]*$" t1.txt t3.txt
Files t1.txt and t3.txt differ
bash#> diff -BbaNq -I "^[:blank:]*$" t1.txt t3.txt
Files t1.txt and t3.txt differ
bash#>
```

Any help in what the syntax for `diff` would be would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
diff -wBt -u t1.txt t2.txt
```

Comment: '-u' is irrelevant to your question, I just like unified format :)

Comment: No -- this doesn't work.  It works for t2 (which has spaces), but not for t3, which has the tab.:

Comment: add 't' switch - it will expand tabs into spaces

Comment: I did a diff -wbBtq t1.txt t3.txt, and I'm still getting "Files t1.txt and t3.txt differ".  It seems that there might be a bug in diff for this...

Comment: Strange, why I get no differences using `diff -wBt` or `diff -wbBtq` between these two files. `diff --version
diff (GNU diffutils) 3.2`

Comment: I'm using 2.8.1, but this is a script I'm planning to distribute, so I don't want to make assumptions about which diff people have installed.  I did find a solution:  `diff -wbBtq -I "^[[:blank:]]*$` in my version.  I'm glad to hear that the newer diff has this resolved.